# What's the significance of the blue glow on Peacemaker?

Tags: wynonna-earp

Peacemaker normally glows orange, when shooting demons, revenants, witches, whatever.

However, we've seen it glow blue twice: once when Wynnona shot Willa, and once when Waverly shot at Rosita.

It's not because of who's shooting it, clearly. It's not because of the character of whom it's shooting *at* (Rosita might not have been so horrible, but Willa was pretty bad, and in any case it still glowed orange when Wynnona shot a few nice revenants previously). And it doesn't seem to be about shooting non-demonic things, either, because (even if witches are demonic), it glowed blue when shooting Rosita, who's definitely a revenant.

So what's up with the blue glow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Tim Rozon (an author of the Wynonna Earp graphic novel by IDW publishing), Peacemaker glows blue when there's a better way to deal with something besides a bullet.

https://mobile.twitter.com/realtimrozon/status/902178828361109505/actions